# Receiving error: message: 'Calendar usage limits exceeded.' with new project with attendees in event object

Tags: node.js, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am receiving an error,

> Calendar usage limits exceeded

When trying to insert an event into a new calendar.

The Attempt is showing up in the API dashboard so I know the credentials are correct.

I have ensured billing is attached, and I have added the service account to the google calendar.

Not sure what else can be adjusted on this, any ideas what else could be causing this error? It says in my quotas that I can do up to 1 million requests, I have done under 50...
EDIT:
**I have discovered that the removal of the attendees from the event object allows the event to insert.**

Comment: @Peter API issues are valid questions on SO there are loads of quota questions and set up of credential questions.

Comment: Hello! Could you provide a a *sanitized*  version of your request body? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael, I've been experiencing the exact same thing. With no attendees, I can insert, but with even one attendee on one event, the event insert fails (403) with a "Calendar usage limits exceeded" message. I have similarly made only a handful of requests. I'm using a service account with Owner permissions, and have tried with attendee emails both inside and outside my org. I have also tried setting sendUpdates: 'none' on the insert request, but it doesn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of quotas.

[image]

Project based quotas: these are the quotas that define what the full project can do.  Your project can make 1 million requests a day.

There are also user based quotas these tend to be related to flood protection a user can max make say 500 requests a second.

There are also write quotas.  A user can max for example insert 50 events per day.

Project based quotas can be increased user based quotas can not. Write quotas can not be increased. Wait until midnight west coast usa time and the quota will reset.

Comment: I appreciate the note, but I have only done 35 attempts to insert with a 100% failure rate, I have received this calendar usage error since my first attempt and did wait until a new day to attempt again thinking perhaps there was an error since it was new.

Comment: Can you do anything else with the API or is it just inserts?

Comment: so it turns out if i remove the attendees from the event object I am submitting it goes through fine. Any thoughts on why this would be. This was working on my old calendar.

Comment: Google has been doing something with event attendees lately notification isn't working with service accounts either there are issues for it.   There has been no official word from Google

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761425) with Google issue tracker for this.

Sorry to not be able to offer more help!